# How to get status of file is playing in Windows Media Player?

Tags: java, media, windows-media-player

I'm doing project about Mini-Lyrics by java-code, so, I want to get take information of mp3 file when **it running on Window Media Player**, for example: About information beginning time, running time, finish time,get Artist, Album, Singer...Please help me, thanks for your answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have an in-built API for it. You can use native, i.e. do it in  C# and call that from Java.

or go for JIntelliType which can help you call windows native commands. https://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/